# Use integrated Intel Graphic card for display and Tesla for Cuda

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, cuda

I have a Tesla C2050 and an integrated graphic card Intel Xeon E3 1200. What I want to do is to use the Intel card for the screen and the Tesla card for doing cuda calculations.

I have installed cuda and the nvidia drivers, and when I run the test programs in the SDK, it works perfectly for the programs *deviceQuery* and *bandwidthtest*, which does not use any opengl, the result only comes on the terminal.

So it is possible to use the Tesla for cuda only.

However, when I try to run the programs under the folder 5_simulations, such as particles, then I get the following error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
freeglut (./particles): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0.0'
```

I don't really know what this error means, is it a driver problem or something else?

I have already tried install mesa-utils.

Regards 
Erik

Comment: Seems your libGL.so is missing. Maybe this brief summary helps: http://osdf.github.io/blog/intel-integrated-graphics-dedicated-gpu-for-cuda-and-ubuntu-1310.html